# PHP loop not returning all possible MySQL query results

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am new to php & MySQL. 
I have a db that contains two tables called person (property owner) and property.
There is a one-to-many relationship between the tables. For instance, a person can own many properties.

I am using php to retrieve data from the db (I have already established a connection with the db).

What I am trying to achieve is this: if a query is carried out for a person's name - (whether it is fname or lname) - then a list of all the properties owned by this person will be displayed in my search results form. The output will be shown as lname, fname, property number, property road, property zipcode.

However, with this code I am only getting two results output per property owner name. :

```
$request = mysql_query("SELECT person.fname, person.lname, property.number, property.road, property.zipcode, 
    FROM person p
        INNER JOIN property py 
            ON p.id = py.p_id
    WHERE p.fname LIKE  '%$search%' 
            OR p.lname LIKE  '%$search%' 
            ORDER BY p.lname");

$number = mysql_num_rows($request);
    if ($number == 0){
        $result .= 'No results'.'  '.$search;
    } else { 

    $propertyinfo= array();
    $count = 0;

    $real = false;
    $real_within_array = 0;


    while ($nrow = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        $lname = $nrow['lname'];
        $real = false;
        for ($l = 0; $l < count($propertyinfo); $l++)
        {
            if ($propertyinfo[$l][0] == $lname)
            {
                $real = true;
                $real_within_array = $l;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($real)
        {
            $fname = $nrow['fname'];
            $lname = $nrow['lname'];
            $number = $nrow['number'];
            $road = $nrow['road'];
            $zipcode = $nrow['zipcode'];



            $propertyinfo[$real_within_array][1][1] = $fname;
            $propertyinfo[$real_within_array][2][1] = $lname;
            $propertyinfo[$real_within_array][3][1] = $number;
            $propertyinfo[$real_within_array][4][1] = $road;
            $propertyinfo[$real_within_array][5][1] = $zipcode;

        }
        else
        {
            // Get all the data from the row.
            $fname = $nrow['fname'];
            $lname = $nrow['lname'];
            $number = $nrow['number'];
            $road = $nrow['road'];
            $zipcode = $nrow['zipcode'];

            $propertyinfo[$real_within_array][1] = $fname;
            $propertyinfo[$real_within_array][2]= $lname;
            $propertyinfo[$real_within_array][3][0] = $number;
            $propertyinfo[$real_within_array][4][0] = $road;
            $propertyinfo[$real_within_array][5][0] = $zipcode;
            $count++;
        }
    }
```

Example: Adam Smith owns 4 properties, but I will only get a result of two of his properties instead of all 4 in a list.

Please help. I have tried my very best to sort this out but I seem to have stumbled upon a difficult problem.

Your help is much appreciated. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a logical error; 
when you defined $propertyinfo=array(); it's size is 0, therefore the code withing the block of
for ($l =0; $l< count($propertyinfo); $l) will only start running after some values has been assigned to $propertyinfo.

Comment: Therefore the code within the block of for ($l =0;$l... I'm a little confused as to what you mean.

Comment: The answer was not displaying completely but i've now edited it.

Comment: I have tried to assign the $result variable output to the array and it still is not working. Please could you help.

Answer (score 0):

What is `$uqery`? Maybe:

```
while ($nrow = mysql_fetch_array($request)){
```

You would see this with:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

As for all the other stuff it's impossible to tell without knowing what `$propertyinfo` looks like.  Very convoluted looking so I don't follow.

Comment: Sorry it was supposed to be $request

Comment: I have added in the error porting statement and yet the error still does not come up. Programming is really hard. I truly admire those who are experts at it - it's not easy getting your head around it.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `while(($nrow=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))!=null)` to cycle on your query results